# Return England, Scotland etc instead of United Kingdom from Lat/Long values

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-3

I need to find out whether the user is accessing from England, Scotland, Ireland or other from the Lat/Long values I have.

However, I've been using Google Maps API, but this returns United Kingdom.

Is there a way of doing this with Google Maps or is there another API which will return the individual countries?

Answer (score 1):

You could define bounding polygon for each region and then check whether the lat/long point is inside.

https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon

Comment: And you could use selected UK cities lat/long values to help define the large area polygons. See http://www.mapsofworld.com/lat_long/united-kingdom/united-kingdom-lat-long.html.

Comment: How would I know the boundaries of the different countries? :S

Comment: Draw the polygon along the border line. I guess it doesn't have to be 100% accurate. Quick example: http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=5&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=210482407182953405460.0004a8913a611c22ee21c

Answer (score 0):

try [geocode](http://code.google.com/intl/vi/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse.html)

I used

```
var gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
gc.geocode({'location': ll}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {       
                var results = results[0].address_components;
            }
        }
    });
```

and the results its look like this :

```
results[0].formatted_address: "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
results[1].formatted_address: "Williamsburg, NY, USA",
results[2].formatted_address: "New York 11211, USA",
results[3].formatted_address: "Kings, New York, USA",
results[4].formatted_address: "Brooklyn, New York, USA",
results[5].formatted_address: "New York, New York, USA",
results[6].formatted_address: "New York, USA",
results[7].formatted_address: "United States"
```

Comment: I believe this will still return United Kingdom?

Comment: it's depend in lat-long value, you enter the lat-long values then geocode return the result

Comment: I understand that the returned value will differ depending on Lat/Long values, but I'm currently situated in England. If I was to put my Lat/Long values into this script, I believe it would return "United Kingdom", whereas I need more specific info (ie. England)